# Xcode 10 and super.tearDown

Tags: xcode, xctest, teardown

Since Xcode 10.1(maybe 10) when I create a Unit test file I don't have calls super.tearDown() and super.setUp() .

I've not seen such changes in release notes.

In documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods are still here.

So my question should I still write super.tearDown() and super.setUp()?

```
class SomethingTests: XCTestCase {  

    override func setUp() {  
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.  
    }  

    override func tearDown() {  
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.  
    }  

    func testExample() {  
        // This is an example of a functional test case.  
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.  
    }  

    func testPerformanceExample() {  
        // This is an example of a performance test case.  
        self.measure {  
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For a direct subclass of XCTestCase, there never was any change of behavior for not calling `super.setUp()`. That's because `setUp` and `tearDown` are template methods with empty implementations at the top level.

Though there's no change in behavior, omitting the calls to `super` means that if you create a test hierarchy with more than one level, you'll have to add them back.

When would you ever have more than one level? There are two cases:

- When you want to reuse the same tests for different scenarios.
- When you subclass XCTestCase to make a customized helper.

These don't happen every day. But they do happen. Deciding "I need it here, but I don't need it there" is perilous. So I'd just call `super` all the time.